# Windows cannot find 'C:\file_name.bat.' Make sure you typed name correctly, and then try again

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, virus

I have a problem with running `*.bat` file.
It looks like a virus.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my Windows?
How to solve it?

I can run `*.bat` when I use `Run as Administrator`.
I tried to delete a `.bat` from: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've just messed something up in your registry. I can send you a .reg file to fix it. I have windows 8 so this should work if you have 8, 7 or vista. Not so sure if it will work for XP though, in witch case you shouldn't be running it anyway.

Download -> http://www.4shared.com/file/m3gRIasace/Bat_regfix.html

Simply run the .reg file and it should restore the missing .bat extension. Then i suggest running a scan with Malwarebytes afterwards. Link -> www.malwarebytes.org

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still have same behaviour.

Comment: Humm you might just need to re install your copy of windows, you can do this without deleting all your files though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure cmd.exe is in System32,i placed it on desktop and i had the same problem as you.